# CRM Analytics Connector to Snowflake - Password Only or Private Key

Tags: crm-analytics

I am trying to setup the CRM Analytics Connector with Snowflake but I am getting an error.  The documentation (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_integrate_connectors_snowflake_settings.htm&type=5)

While it says the following when discussing Authentication types:

> Authentication Type
> The variety of authentication used for this connection. Accepted values are "OAuth", "Password", or "PrivateKey".
>
> If you use OAuth, enter a value in the Named Credential field.
> If you use Password, enter a value in the Username and Password fields.
> If you use PrivateKey, enter a value in the Username, Private Key, and Private Key Passphrase fields.

and implies that if authenticating with Password, you don't need the Named Credential or Private Key fields. Earlier it was a bit more vague and made it sound setting up and OAuth provider (i.e. Okta) was required.

I attempted to setup the connection filling in just Username and Password of the Service User we use for other Snowflake connections along with the Account Name, Database, Schema, Role and Warehouse but I'm getting a access error 403.

[image]

My question is, do I need to go through the Oauth / Named Credential / Private Key steps or is there something additional I need our Snowflake team to configure on there end? As I said, we successfully use these credentials for other connections such as PowerBI.